# Regular expression missing one item

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I have this text

```
System Name: MetroCore-PTX5K-Bur-601-1-re0
Port id: et-7/1/19
System Name: MetroCore-PTX5K-Bur-601-1-re0
Port id: 21
System Name: ProCurve 6120G/XG Blade Switch
Port id: 1106
System Name - not advertised
Port id: 1105
System Name - not advertised
Port id: et-7/1/0
System Name: MetroCore-PTX5K-Abar-422-1-re0
Port id: et-3/1/0
System Name: MetroCore-PTX5K-Abar-422-1-re0
Port id: Te0/0/0/0
System Name: UPE9-TYBHDNAX-2.stc.com.sa
```

I am using this regex

`System Name: (.*)((.stc.com.sa)|(-re0_NOPAT)|(-re0))`

It is missing 1 string with System Name: ProCurve 6120G/XG Blade Switch

Comment: Try [`(?m)System Name: (.*?)(?=\.stc\.com\.sa|-re0_NOPAT|-re0|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/HpiEKe/2)

Comment: beautiful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?m)System Name: (.*?)(?=\.stc\.com\.sa|-re0_NOPAT|-re0|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HpiEKe/2).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - the multiline modifier that makes `$` match end of lines
- `System Name:` - a literal substring
- - a space
- `(.*?)(?=\.stc\.com\.sa|-re0_NOPAT|-re0|$)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of:

  - `.stc.com.sa` or
  - `-re0_NOPAT` or
  - `-re0` or
  - `$` - end of line.

Answer (score 0):

None of your optional groups match that string. Try something like this:

```
System Name: (.*)((.stc.com.sa)|(-re0_NOPAT)|(-re0)|(Blade Switch))
```

This would render: `ProCurve 6120G/XG`

What part of the string you match with the last group depends on other values you might want to filter for.

If you do not want anything removed but `System Name:` you can just make the last group of groups optional:

```
System Name: (.*)((.stc.com.sa)|(-re0_NOPAT)|(-re0)|(Switch))?
```

This would render: `ProCurve 6120G/XG Blade Switch`

Comment: We can't see the whole data set, so they might have a reason they're more specific

Comment: the whole idea is that I want to exclude .stc.com.sa)|(-re0_NOPAT)|(-re0 from string